# Why getting info form fields is not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I'm trying to validate a form field for a college exercise, but I'm not succeeding. I do not understand clearly where is the error. Can someone tell me where is the error and why? I do not need the code to copy and paste. I need to understand what is wrong. The function `checkUsername(valor)` appears as it in the test document.

I appreciate any help.

```html
<input type="text" 
  class="input" id="username" name="username" 
  placeholder="nombre de usuario" required />
```

```js
function checkUsername(valor){
  valor = document.getElementById('username').value;
  if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{4,30}$/g.test(valor)){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is wrong, don't put image of code. [add real code in markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: One thing you may be missing is the mechanism to invoke your `checkUsername` function. I don't see that in either of your samples. Were you given any instruction on how to do that? On a side note, it would be better if you could include both the HTML and JavaScript code directly in the question rather than as links to images.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Are you even getting the form input value? Is your function always returning `true` or always returning `false`? Your question is not detailed enough

Comment: why are you erasing your `valor` argument ?

Comment: why you didn't call your function `checkUsername()` ?

Comment: what is your regular expression is supposed to do ?

Comment: 1. why are you erasing your valor argument ? R/. Then how can I get the input value?

Comment: 2. why you didn't call your function checkUsername() ? R/. Because it is required in the test instruction (I do not why, but they are asking that)

Comment: 3. what is your regular expression is supposed to do ? R/. For field validation, doesn't it?

Comment: Your regular expression looks fine. In your function you are immediately overwriting the `valor` argument. Generally when you a function receives an argument, you expect the function to use what was passed in. However, I suspect that the problem is that the function is not getting called. There must be something that calls the function. For example, you may attach it to the `onsubmit` event on your form.

Comment: I think not, I am testing it in the Edge console and it gets the value with no problem, even returns the true. It must be somewhere related to the "valor" argument. I'm just checking if my syntax is OK.

Comment: @JackA. you were right, I was misunderstanding the function concept and using the parameter wrongly. There were no need to use the parameter, the function worked perfectly with no parameter. Thank you for your apport.

Comment: 3* bis : so what are validation criterias ?

Comment: 1* this is nonsens, `valor` is the function agument, it's certainly contains some value, and your code ignore what this  value could be, because you change this value by `#username.value`

Comment: 2* so your question is incomplete, in this kind of question, your are supposed to show  a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @alejorojas2k Good to hear that you're moving forward. Is your question answered at this point?

Comment: Yes! The problem was solved. I apologize not answered immediately. Thank you for your time and knowledge.